# How to append an HTML element to a button via an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been working on a feature within a web application that is JS-based. The following is my plain language idea:

1. Button on the bottom left hand corner.
2. Button will be visible only after scrolling begins.
3. When pressed the button will launch a new window to display a pdf.

So far I have gotten this to work with on individual pages (too cumbersome) with the following code:

```js
// JavaScript Document
 $(document).ready(function(){
  //added this for DW
  'use strict';
  $('#ap1').append('<div id="formInstructions" class="btn btn-aprs"><span class="fa fa-question-circle"></span>&nbspForm&nbspInstructions</div>');
  $(window).scroll(function () {

  //the original funtion was != 0
  if ($(this).scrollTop() !== 0) {
   $('#formInstructions').fadeIn();
  } else {
   $('#formInstructions').fadeOut();
  }
 });
 $('#formInstructions').click(function(){
  window.open("../static/instructions/ap2_instrns.pdf", "_blank", "toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no, statusbar=no,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=600,height=600");
  return false;
 });
 });
```

```css
#formInstructions {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 10px;
 left: 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- this is in element in the HMTL file -->

<div id="ap1">&nbsp;</div>
```

This is a screenshot of the working example in an individual page:

[image: screenshot of the working example]

My overall goal is to build one script to automate the process throughout an application; the following is my first try at making this a reality:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
      var arr = [ "#ap1", "#ap2", "#ap3", "#ap4", "#ap5", "#ap6", "#ap7", "#ap8", "#ap9", "#ap10", "#ap11", "#ap12", "#ap13", "#ap14", "#ap15", "#ap17", "#apa", "#apb", "#apc", "#apd", "#ape", "#apf, "#apg", "#aph", "#api", "#apj", "#apk", "#apl", "#apm", "#apn", "#apo", "#app, "#apq" ];

      $(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery.each( arr, function( i, val ) {
          $(arr).append('<div id="formInstructions" class="btn btn-aprs"><span class="fa fa-question-circle"></span>&nbspForm&nbspInstructions</div>');

          $(window).scroll(function () {
            //the original function was != 0
                if ($(this).scrollTop() !== 0) {
                    $('#formInstructions').fadeIn();
                } else {
                    $('#formInstructions').fadeOut();
                }
            });
          if (arr = '#ap1') {
            $('#formInstructions').click(function(){
                    window.open("../static/instructions/ap1_instrns.pdf", "_blank", "toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no, statusbar=no,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=600,height=600");
                    return false;
          } else if (arr = '#ap2'){
            $('#formInstructions').click(function(){
              window.open("../static/instructions/ap2_instrns.pdf", "_blank", "toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no, statusbar=no,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=600,height=600");
              return false;
          } else if (arr = '#ap3') {
            $('#formInstructions').click(function(){
                    window.open("../static/instructions/ap3_instrns.pdf", "_blank", "toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no, statusbar=no,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=600,height=600");
                    return false;
          } else if (arr = '#ap4') {
            $('#formInstructions').click(function(){
                    window.open("../static/instructions/ap4_instrns.pdf", "_blank", "toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no, statusbar=no,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=600,height=600");
                    return false;
          } else if (arr = '#ap5'){
            $('#formInstructions').click(function(){
              window.open("../static/instructions/ap5_instrns.pdf", "_blank", "toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no, statusbar=no,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=600,height=600");
              return false;
          }  else {
            return ("Opps there is something wrong going on!!");
          }
        });
        });
</script>
```

I can't seem to get it to work. Is there a way to condense this?

Comment: The first "*glaring problem*" that I can see is that all of your `if` conditionals use a single equals sign instead of two or three. A single equals sign **assigns**, whereas two equal signs (`==`) **compares**. Three equals signs (`===`) additionally checks against the type. I'm sure this was just a typo though, as you do this correctly in your singular page :)

Comment: have css class called `hidden` which is set to `display:none` applied to button in markup. Listen for `scroll` event and `classList.remove('hidden').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Obsidian mentioned there are a few errors in the code above, i have put something together that i hope will help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var arr = [ "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4" ];

    $.each( arr, function( i, val ) {

      // you need to use the value(val) not the array(arr)
      $('#'+val).append('<div id="formInstructions" class="btn btn_'+val+'"><span class="fa fa-question-circle"></span>&nbspForm&nbspInstructions</div>');
      // #a1 ,#b1 ...

       $(window).scroll(function() {              
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scroll >= 0) {
                $('.btn_'+val).fadeIn();
                //.btn_a1 , btn_b1...
            } else {
                $('.btn_'+val).fadeOut();
                //.btn_a1, btn_b1...
            }
        });

        $('.btn_'+val).click(function(){  
            // now you can do the if statement  
            if (val == 'a1') {
                window.open("../static/instructions/ap1_instrns.pdf", "_blank", "toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no, statusbar=no,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=600,height=600");
            } else if (val == 'a2'){
                window.open("../static/instructions/ap2_instrns.pdf", "_blank", "toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no, statusbar=no,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=600,height=600");
            } else if (val == 'a3') {
                window.open("../static/instructions/ap3_instrns.pdf", "_blank", "toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no, statusbar=no,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=600,height=600");       
            }  else {   
                return ("Opps there is something wrong going on!!");
            }     
            return false;
        });// END CLICK
    }); //END EACH
});
```

Comment: Jim - Thanks for putting this together. It was a great base.

Comment: No problem, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Obsidian, Ron, and Jim - thanks for the feedback. I have taken your feedback and made changes to the file and now everything works beautifully. See the modified code below!!

```js
//find and append instructions
$(document).ready(function() {
  'use strict';

  var arr = ["ap1", "ap2", "ap3", "ap4", "ap5", "ap6", "ap7", "ap8", "ap9", "ap10", "ap11", "ap12", "ap13", "ap14", "ap15", "ap17", "apa", "apb", "apc", "apd", "ape", "apf", "apg", "apj", "aph", "api", "apj", "apk", "apl", "apm", "apn", "apo", "app"];

  $.each(arr, function(i, val) {

    // you need to use the value(val) not the array(arr)
    $('#' + val).append('<div id="formInstructions" class="btn btn-aprs"><span class="fa fa-question-circle"></span>&nbspForm&nbspInstructions</div>');
    // #a1 ,#b1 ...

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      //this makes the button disappear once at top of the screen
      if (scroll !== 0) {
        $('#formInstructions').fadeIn();
        //.btn_a1 , btn_b1...
      } else {
        $('#formInstructions').fadeOut();
        //.btn_a1, btn_b1...
      }
    });

    $('#formInstructions').click(function() {
      // now you can do the if statement  
      if (val === 'ap1') {
        window.open("../static/instructions/ap1_instrns.pdf", "_blank", "toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no, statusbar=no,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=600,height=600");
      } else if (val === 'ap2') {
        window.open("../static/instructions/ap2_instrns.pdf", "_blank", "toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no, statusbar=no,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=600,height=600");
      } else if (val === 'ap3') {
        window.open("../static/instructions/ap3_instrns.pdf", "_blank", "toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no, statusbar=no,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=600,height=600");
      } else {
        return ("Opps there is something wrong going on!!");
      }
      return false;
    }); // END CLICK
  }); //END EACH
}); //DOCUMENT READY
```

```css
#formInstructions {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="ap1"></div>
```